# How to remove ID's from wp_enqueue_style?

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-style

How to remove ID's from wp_enqueue_styles ? Check below picture

[image: Noted in Green color]

Comment: Why do you want to remove them?

Comment: No reason technically but i want to make code less simple wp theme and it feel not good as well

Comment: You're going to have to write a filter in your `functions.php` file for it that will run with each page load.

Comment: Can't get you or can't understand

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`style_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_tag/) filter:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {
    return str_replace( " id='$handle-css'", '', $tag );
}, 10, 2 );
```